# Oracle pagination: select distinct with no explicit order by

Tags: oracle, pagination

I am using oracle 12c and trying to write a query with pagination. In a simple case one would either use

```
SELECT * FROM T OFFSET a FETCH NEXT b ROWS ONLY;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT t.*,ROWNUM AS rn FROM (
                SELECT t.* FROM test_table t
                 WHERE col = ?
                 ORDER BY order_col) t
         WHERE ROWNUM <= b
) WHERE rn >= a;
```

But in my case I have two issues:

1. I don't have order_column as my query is generated on the fly against not well defined tables, so I don't know if they have some column I can order by. So, the question here is can I simply use ROWID in that case to ORDER BY ROWID?
2. Most inner select or the original(not paginated) query contains DISTINCT, so, ORDER BY ROWID results in exception. 
   SELECT distinct column FROM T ORDER BY ROWID -> "not a selected expression"

So, my questions are how to do the pagination without predefined order_column and how to use "order by rowid" with "distinct".

Comment: So why not just append rowid column as part of every select statement?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you. "select distinct col,rowid from t order by rowid" will select pairs of distinct col and rowid, i.e. (VAL1, 0000AAAFFFA), (VAL1, 0000AAAFFFB), (VAL2, 0000AAAFFFC), (VAL3, 0000AAAFFFD). But duplicating VAL1 is a wrong result, I want to collapse them.

Comment: if you are generating the queries, why you don't order by all selected columns?

Comment: It's one of the ideas I have come up with. But wouldn't it significantly drop the performance? I am thinking of doing "order by" with the first column only, but still tiebreaker is required...

Comment: Are you sure that you need to do pagination in SQL?  Rather than simply opening a cursor and letting the client application fetch pages of results?  You can order by a column (or columns) from the `select` list.  That's potentially inefficient depending on the amount of data you're sorting and the available indexes.  You could omit the `order by` and hope that you get mostly the results you expect without missing or duplicating too many rows (which would be an issue anyway if there are other sessions).

Comment: Yes I am sure I need pagination. So, what's about ROWID?

Comment: From oracle documentation "If you delete and reinsert a row with the Import and Export utilities, for example, then its rowid may change. If you delete a row, then Oracle may reassign its rowid to a new row inserted later." Therefore rowid should be unfeasible for sorting

Comment: That's true. But some guarantee is definitely better than no guarantee. The other solution maybe to introduce primary id for all the entities which can be selected and order by that id. I am trying to analyze all the possible solutions.. Thanks